# SQL Query to group the values based on the key column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called SOURCE_CATEGORY with SOURCEID and NAME. I have 4020 and 4025, how is it possible to combine the NAME field based on the SOURCEID using SQL Query?

[image]

I am hoping to get this result, because I wanted to copy the data in MSSQL to MongoDB which can combine the result into array. I only wanted the NAME field in mongodb. Is it possible to custom the SQL in MSSQL to kind of group them?

[image]

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add your simple data and query as text not images so it can be easy for us to help you

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) as follows :

```
select sourceid, string_agg( experience, ',') AS NAME
from source_category
group by sourceid
order by sourceid
```